# Dart language exception when inspecting a set of strings

Tags: dart

I have an object called student which has some string returning getters for firstName and lastName.  It also has a method like this:

```
Set<String> queryTerms() {
  return new Set.from([firstName, lastName]);
}
```

Which seems to compile okay.  When I run it, however, and inspect the result, there seems to be something wrong.  It produces a `CompactLinkedHashSet<String>`, and that thing has a property called `single:` that contains an exception that says "too many elements"...

[image]

Why is this, and how do I fix?  Thanks.

Reproduce this way....

```
class TestClass {
  TestClass();
  String get firstName {
    return 'Lisa';
  }
  String get lastName {
    return 'Simpson';
  }
  Set<String> queryTerms() {
    return new Set.from([firstName, lastName]);
  }
}
```

Elsewhere...

```
TestClass t = new TestClass();
// break here (in VSCode) and inspect t and note the image above
```

Comment: Please edit the code and show a [mcve].  Thanks.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - okay.  see edit.

Comment: The inspector is trying to access a property ([`Set.single`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Iterable/single.html)) that is not valid for the current state of the object (it has more than one element).  Ignore it.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin.  Do you want to make that an answer?  An aside: this one (and `firstWhere` that throws exception for no match) and probably a few others seem too touchy about exceptions.  Seems like the right answer in most empty-collection situations is `null`, not an error.  If my app sees these as exceptions, I can code that in. dart seems to want me to explicitly code for cases where these aren't exceptions.  Does that seem upside down to you?